# Accessing private pointer variables in C++ class methods

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:

```
#include<iostream>

class Test {
  private:
    int iNum;
    int *ptr;

  public:
    Test(int iFirst, int iSecond);
    void setNum(int iValue);
    int getNum();
    int getFirstNum();
    int getSecondNum();
};

Test::Test(int iFirst, int iSecond) {
  int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
  ptr[0] = iFirst;
  ptr[1] = iSecond;
}

void Test::setNum(int iValue) {
  iNum = iValue;
}

int Test::getNum() {
  return iNum;
}

int Test::getFirstNum() {
  return ptr[0];
}

int Test::getSecondNum() {
  return ptr[1];
}

int main() {
  Test oTest(3,4);

  std::cout << oTest.getFirstNum() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I just don't understand why I am getting junk value when I try to return ptr[0] using getFirstNum() method. Please enlighten me on how this behaves in memory and possible ways to fix it. Thank youi

Comment: in constructor you initialize a local variable `int *ptr` instead member `ptr`. Just write `ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);`

Comment: In constructor, `int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);` the local `ptr` shadows the class member `ptr`

Comment: Thus, access `ptr` in `getFirstNum` yield an undefined behavior

Comment: Also consider using `new` rather than malloc in c++

Comment: Oh no.. I am so embarrassed. haha.. crazy mistake.. Thank you very much. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Thank you very much guys

Comment: Don't forget to free that mempory and also keep an eye out for the Rule of Three. [What is the Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Funny you should ask that. Just linked the answer.

Comment: Surely.. need to delete. Thank you. I just didn't include it here. Thanks! Thanks!

Comment: Better to not `new` the array in the first place. Rule of zero.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in your constructor:

```
int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
```

Here, you're declaring a variable named `ptr`. However, you already have a variable named `ptr` as a member of your class. This is called *shadowing*. Your compiler will always use the version of the variable with the narrowest scope, which in this case is the one that you declare in the constructor. That gets thrown away when your constructor returns, and the `ptr` in the class never gets touched.

To fix this, don't re-declare the variable:

```
ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
```

Comment: I don't understand why don't you close this question as a typo instead

Comment: @Danh It's not a typo, it's an understando

Comment: @immibis anyway, this question still should be closed, _While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 2):

`int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);`

Inside constructor you have created a new pointer `ptr` thus shadowing the class member `ptr`. As it's a new pointer, your class member `ptr` is never initialized. Remove `int *` from this line and that will initialize class member `ptr`.

`ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);`

Another thing is since you are allocating memory dynamically for `ptr` you must delete it in destructor. Otherwise you will leak memory.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you close this question as a typo instead

Comment: @Danh I'm not sure whether this is a typo. To me it seems that OP doesn't have the idea of shadowing member variables which needs to be clarified.

Comment: If you take 1 minute to read OP's comment, he indicated it clearly that it's just a typo

Comment: Ya, saw his comment just now :-(.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>

class Test {
private:
    int iNum;
    int *ptr;

public:
    Test(int iFirst, int iSecond);
    ~Test();
    void setNum(int iValue);
    int getNum();
    int getFirstNum();
    int getSecondNum();
};

Test::Test(int iFirst, int iSecond) {
    ptr = new int[2];
    ptr[0] = iFirst;
    ptr[1] = iSecond;
}

Test::~Test()
{
    delete[] ptr;
}

void Test::setNum(int iValue) {
    iNum = iValue;
}

int Test::getNum() {
    return iNum;
}

int Test::getFirstNum() {
    return ptr[0];
}

int Test::getSecondNum() {
    return ptr[1];
}

int main() {
    Test oTest(3, 4);

    std::cout << oTest.getFirstNum() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You were treating it like c, and not c++. I fixed the issues I saw, you were using malloc and not new, plus you were making a new int*ptr and not using the member one, hence when you called it in a getter function it was not valid.

Also a destructor and delete the memory.

Comment: I'm not sure why I got downvoted, by saying he needs to delete something he dynamically allocated. The default dtor is not going to do that. He could use a smart pointer, etc. instead if he wanted to.

Comment: In introducing a "fix" your also introduced serious bugs. Satisfying the rule of three would be the bare minimum required, but you could also do away with the explicit dynamic allocation entirely (rule of zero.)